# Sqlite: compare two databases and update older - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sqlite

I've two DB, let's say **A_old.sqlite** and **A_new.sqlite**.
Both have many tables but new db has one (or more) table with not equal fields number.

For example:

- A_**old**.sqlite has table *Person* with fields name and surname.
- A_**new**.sqlite has table *Person* with fields name, surname and address.

From shell I can dump each db and see where is the differences:

```
   echo .dump | sqlite3 A_old.sqlite > A_old.sqlite.dump
   echo .dump | sqlite3 A_new.sqlite > A_new.sqlite.dump
   diff A_old.sqlite A_new.sqlite
```

Question is: how can I update schema in OLD db without parse manually *diff* output? (in this case I need to add field 'address' to table *Person*)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You want to tell what the difference is between two things without looking at the differences? What sort of solution are you expecting? How can that work? I am not being sarcastic - just hoping that your explanation will help understand the question.

Comment: I meant "manually" parse diff output.. I try with 'patch' program, but I'm not sure is what I need..

Comment: So you want to automate/script the update process - yes? So is this script only going to tell you the missing field names, or update all the fields in every record? Must it detect where there are additional fields and delete them? Must it detect missing tables too?

Comment: basically I need to update only schema. So if there are new tables, add it. If there are new field in a table, update it. If has been deleted tables, drop it. And so on. Diff is surely a starting point, but I would like to avoid to write a parser and launch sql command..

Comment: Search for `database version control` like here http://techportal.inviqa.com/2011/01/11/database-version-control/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $olddbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:old.db');
my $newdbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:new.db');

my %oldtables = $olddbh->tables();
my %newtables = $newdbh->tables();
my @oldtablenames;
my @newtablenames;
my $tmp;

print "Tables in new database\n";
print "======================\n";
foreach (%newtables){
   $tmp=$_;
   $tmp =~ s/.*"."//;
   $tmp =~ s/".*//;
   next if /sqlite_/;
   print $tmp,"\n";
   push(@newtablenames,$tmp);
}
print  "\n";

print "Tables in old database\n";
print "======================\n";
foreach (%oldtables){
   $tmp=$_;
   $tmp =~ s/.*"."//;
   $tmp =~ s/".*//;
   next if /sqlite_/;
   print $tmp,"\n";
   push(@oldtablenames,$tmp);
}
print  "\n";

# Check no tables missing from old
foreach (keys %newtables){
   printf "Table: %s is missing in old database\n",$_ if ! exists $oldtables{$_};
}

# Check no tables in old but not in new
foreach (keys %oldtables){
   printf "Table: %s is superfluous in old database\n",$_ if ! exists $newtables{$_};
}

# Work out tablenames common to new and old
my @common;
foreach my $table (@newtablenames){
   foreach my $oldtable (@oldtablenames){
      if($oldtable eq $table){
        push(@common,$table);
        last;
      }
   }
}

print  "\n";
# For all tables, check fields match
foreach my $table (@common){
   my $i;
   printf "Checking fields in common table: %s\n",$table;

   my @newfields;
   my $sth = $newdbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT 1");
   $sth->execute();
   my $nnfields=$sth->{NUM_OF_FIELDS};
   for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nnfields ; $i++ ) {
        push(@newfields,$sth->{NAME}->[$i]);
   }

   my @oldfields;
   $sth = $olddbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT 1");
   $sth->execute();
   my $nofields=$sth->{NUM_OF_FIELDS};
   for ($i = 0 ; $i < $nofields ; $i++ ) {
        push(@oldfields,$sth->{NAME}->[$i]);
   }
   if($nnfields != $nofields){
      printf "Number of fields differs: %d vs %d\n",$nnfields,$nofields;
   }

}
```

Which will give output like this:

```
Tables in new database
======================
AdditionalTable
Person

Tables in old database
======================
OldTable
Person

Table: "main"."AdditionalTable" is missing in old database
Table: "main"."OldTable" is superfluous in old database

Checking fields in common table: Person
Number of fields differs: 3 vs 2
```

Comment: thank you for the support! Script or handmade program is what I want to avoid, but if I wont find anything else I'll consider this script!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem and I doubt you will find a trivial way to solve it.

For one thing, the `.dump` command will emit the `sql` column of the `sqlite_master` table.  This value is the SQL that was used to create the table.  The problem here is that the column order may be different but equivalent.

```
vagrant@precise32:~/.ash$ sqlite3 new.db <<< "create table foo(a int, b int);"
vagrant@precise32:~/.ash$ sqlite3 old.db <<< "create table foo(b int, a int);"
vagrant@precise32:~/.ash$ sqlite3 new.db <<< .dump | grep foo
CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b int);
vagrant@precise32:~/.ash$ sqlite3 old.db <<< .dump | grep foo
CREATE TABLE foo(b int, a int);
```

If you ignore this problem, you still have to keep in mind that the emitted values are just the SQL used to create the tables.  You will have to parse that regardless if you want to be able to programmatically add columns to the tables in the "old" schema.

One approach that won't work would be to create a *new* database using the new schema and then use the `INSERT` statements from the `.dump` of the old database to populate the new db.

```
sqlite3 new.db <<< .dump | grep -v "^INSERT" | sqlite3 temp.db
sqlite3 old.db <<< .dump | grep "^INSERT" | sqlite3 temp.db
```

This fails because the `INSERT` statements returned by `.dump` are positional.  If you could somehow insert the column names in parentheses after the table name, it *might* work.  To do this you would need to parse the column names and create a comma-separated list of them.  Then each insert line would need to include that list after the table name.  This seems like a job for awk, but after taking a couple quick stabs at it I can see it's not trivial

If you want to get the list of column names manually and put it into a variable, you can possibly approximate the solution like this:

```
sqlite3 new.db <<< .dump | grep -v "^INSERT" | sqlite3 temp.db
OLD_NAMES_CSV="b,a"
sqlite3 old.db <<< .dump \
  | grep "^INSERT" \
  | sed -e "s: VALUES: ($OLD_NAMES_CSV) VALUES:" \
  | sqlite3 temp.db
```

After this, `temp.db` should have the data from `old.db` but use the schema from `new.db`.

This won't work if you are renaming columns or deleting them in the new schema, but it sounds like it might be a possible solution for you.

For anything harder than this, I would recommend writing something in python.

Comment: +1 for "column order". I need to update schemas only, so I don't need to do any "inserto into...values..;" I need to do "alter table A add newColumn columnType" or "create table newTable". And the same for remove/drop.

Comment: This approach should work, although it will make a copy of your data into `temp.db`.  Anyway, that may be a preferable solution in case something goes wrong - your old database should remain intact.  Just make sure that `new.db` has the schema you want.